# How to handle values of values of values

Tags: c#, list, object, recursion

I'm reading in a text file that contains data for 3D elements and store them in a dictionary `dict` in C#. The main objects are `OPEN_SHELL`s and `CLOSED_SHELL`s. These contain multiple `ADVANCED_FACE`s. These again contain a single `FACE_OUTER_BOUND` and multiple `FACE_BOUND`s. These again contain more values and so on until there are finally numerical values.

For now I have a class `Step` that contains

```
List<List>string>> closedShell;         //contains all closed shells with their values
List<List<string>> openShell;           //contains all open shells with their values
List<List<string>> closedShellAdvFace;  //contains all closed advanced faces...
List<List<string>> openShellAdvFace;    //contains all open advanced faces...
...
```

I iterate through each list to get the next values and so on. Now this doesn't seem really efficient as I'm using duplicate code for closed and open lists.
An examplary code for this:

```
  string closedShellKey = "";
        string closedShellValue = "";
        string openShellKey = "";
        string openShellValue = "";

 // For CLOSED_SHELLs
        for (int shellListIndex = 0; shellListIndex < stepObj.GetClosedShells().Count; shellListIndex++)
        {
            for (int valuesCount = 1; valuesCount < stepObj.GetClosedShells()[shellListIndex].Count - 1; valuesCount++)
            {
                if (dict.ContainsKey(stepObj.GetClosedShells()[shellListIndex][valuesCount]))
                {
                    closedShellKey = stepObj.GetClosedShells()[shellListIndex][valuesCount];
                    dict.TryGetValue(closedShellKey, out closedShellValue);
                    stepObj.SetCsAdvFace(SplitValues(closedShellValue));
                } else
                {
                    //Throw Exception
                }
            }
        }


        // For OPEN_SHELLs
        for (int shellListIndex = 0; shellListIndex < stepObj.GetOpenShells().Count; shellListIndex++)
        {                
            for (int valuesCount = 1; valuesCount < stepObj.GetOpenShells()[shellListIndex].Count - 1; valuesCount++)
            {
                if (dict.ContainsKey(stepObj.GetOpenShells()[shellListIndex][valuesCount]))
                {
                    openShellKey = stepObj.GetOpenShells()[shellListIndex][valuesCount];
                    dict.TryGetValue(openShellKey, out openShellValue);
                    stepObj.SetOsAdvFace(SplitValues(openShellValue));
                } else
                {
                    //Throw Exception
                }
            }
        }
```

This goes on for the next values, etc.
What would be a really good and efficient way to implement each of these steps?
Maybe create an `openShellObject` and a `closedShellObject` to further seperate?
How would I handle data that contains different data that again contains further different data, etc.?

Hope this is clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that `Dictionary.TryGetValue` already does the work of `Dictionary.ContainsKey` so you only need the former.

If I understand this, you need to iterate over multiple collections, applying an operation that varies only in one step, according to each collection category, e.g. closed face, open face, etc. How to separate that step from the iteration code? I'd suggest either Template Method pattern or Method As Parameter (MAP). For this problem I'd probably choose MAP because the collection items vary by category not data type, and probably it means less coding.

In the pseudocode below I've assumed that the final step in each iteration always involves a method like `stepObj.SetCsAdvFace` that takes a `string[]` value returned by `SplitValues`. This is why, in the Apply method below, the parameter `method` is a delegate that takes a `string[]` parameter, so it matches either `stepObj.SetCsAdvFace` or `stepObj.SetOsAdvFace`, whichever is required for the relevant collection.

```
private void Apply(List<List<string>> list, Action<string[]> method)
{
    foreach (var items in list)
    {
        for (int valuesIndex = 1; valuesIndex < items.Count - 1; valuesIndex++)
        {
            var key = items[valuesIndex];
            string values;
            if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out values))
            {
                method(SplitValues(values));
            }
            else
            {
                //Throw Exception
            }
        }
    }
}

Apply(stepObj.GetClosedShells(), stepObj.SetCsAdvFace);
Apply(stepObj.GetOpenShells(), stepObj.SetOsAdvFace);
...
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a really nice step ahead for me. Never used methods as parameters.

Comment: @MikeDelta - Glad to be of assistance, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

First get rid of two `for` loops, use `IEnumerable` instead:

```
var allShellKeys = stepObj.GetClosedShells().Union(stepObj.GetOpenShells()).SelectMany(i => i.Skip(1).Take(i.Count() - 2))
```

Then you can iterate over all values in one loop:

```
string anyShellValue;

foreach (var anyShellKey in allShellKeys)
{
    if (dict.TryGetValue(anyShellKey, out anyShellValue))
    {
        stepObj.SetCsAdvFace(SplitValues(anyShellValue));
    }
    else
    {
        //Throw Exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I get the idea, thank you. Didn't know that approach works as well